# python iterate through all possible sequences (pipe network)

Tags: python, list

I have multiple lists of pipe names and corresponding list of junction names.

I also have two lists that have the upstream and downstream
junction of the pipes (To and From).

eg.

```
Pipes = [4000111858, 4000111839, 4000111848, 4000111871]

Junction = [4000068991, 4000068981, 4000069000, 4000069012, 4000237981]

From = [4000068991, 4000068981, 4000069000, 4000069012]

To = [4000069012, 4000068991, 4000069012, 4000237981]
```

I am able to find the last junction in the sequence as it will not be in from list (the outlet), and then find the last pipe from here.

```
Outlet = []

Outlet_Pipe = []

for j in Junction:

    if j not in From:

        Outlet.append(j)

    for j, value in enumerate(Junction, -1):

        if value in Outlet:

            Outlet_Pipe.append(Pipes[j])
```

I need to build a list (or multiple lists) of all possible pipe sequences from upstream to downstream.
i.e.:

```
[4000111839,4000111858, 4000111871] and [4000111848, 4000111871]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uE6F.png)

Comment: Could you provide more information on what the connection between junctions, to, from and pipes is?

Comment: You probably can solve it using the graph theory.

Comment: I am not sure of what you want. What do you mean by "from upstream to downstream"? The values in your example are not in either of the `From` or `To` lists.

Comment: perhaps for your example, provide a simple drawing of what is the goal, and simpler names to discern than 10-digit numbers.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, the lists are ordered so that the index number in the Pipes list corresponds to the index in "To" and "From"

i.e. pipe 4000111839 has corresponding "To" junction of 4000068991 and "From"  4000068981

I included an image of the network to hopefully make more clear, in this example there are two possible sequences of pipes. But I have a lot of other data that I need to also solve for with many possible sequences

Answer (score 0):

## My test network

I made a slight adaptation to your network to see how my code would fare against forks

[image: My network]

```
import collections
import itertools
```

### Define the pipes

```
Pipe = collections.namedtuple('Pipe', 'pipe start end')

all_pipes = [Pipe(pipe='A', start='a', end='d'),
             Pipe(pipe='B', start='b', end='a'),
             Pipe(pipe='C', start='c', end='d'),
             Pipe(pipe='D', start='d', end='e'),
             Pipe(pipe='E', start='d', end='f'),
            ]
```

if you only have the lists of `Pipes`, `From` and `To` you can create that list like this:

```
all_pipes = [Pipe(*pipe) for pipe in zip(Pipes, From, To)]
```

## Define a Network Class

```
class PipeNetwork():
    def __init__(self, pipes):
        self.pipes = pipes
        names, start, end = list(zip(*pipes))
        self.junctions = set(start + end) # ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
        self.end_points = [k for k, v in collections.Counter(start + end).items() if v == 1]  
        # ['b', 'c', 'e', 'f']
        self.pipes_started = collections.defaultdict(set)
        self.pipes_ended = collections.defaultdict(set)
        for pipe in pipes:
            self.pipes_started[pipe.start].add(pipe)
            self.pipes_ended[pipe.end].add(pipe)
```

This is a class for one-way pipes. You will need slight adaptations for 2-way pipes

### Method to find the possible routes from a given starting point

This check for all the pipes starting in `point` the routes that start at the other end of pipe

```
    def find_routes_from(self, point, route=None):
        # print(route)
        if route is None:
            route = [point]
        elif point in route:
            raise ValueError('circular route')
            # or `return None`
        else:
            route = route + [point]
        if point not in self.pipes_started:
            return [route] if len(route) > 1 else None
        # print(self.pipes_started[point])
        return [r for p in self.pipes_started[point] for r in self.find_routes_from(p.end, route) if r]
```

### Find all routes

this asks the routes starting in all end-points which have pipes leaving from them (returns an iterable

```
    @property
    def all_routes(self):
        return itertools.chain().from_iterable(self.find_routes_from(p) for p in self.end_points if p in self.pipes_started)
```

## Calling everything

```
net = PipeNetwork(pipes=all_pipes)
list(net.all_routes)
```

yields

```
[['b', 'a', 'd', 'f'], ['b', 'a', 'd', 'e'], ['c', 'd', 'f'], ['c', 'd', 'e']]
```